# Changing the keyboard layout (NOT language) based on the input language

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, language, keybindings

I have a Japanese keyboard Macbook running Yosemite.

The input languages (sources) are Japanese and English.

While the input language is Japanese, I want the keyboard layout to be Japanese (this is how it is by default, but I don't want to change this).

While the input language is English, I want to use a standard QWERTY layout (in other words, the `;` key should be `;`/`:` (like QWERTY), not `;`/`+` (like Japanese layout).  How can I change the keyboard layout when I change the input language?

Comment: You could try using text replacements in system prefs/keyboard/text.  Otherwise I think you would have to create a custom layout with Ukelele or a similar program that modifies the JIS version of the US layout to work the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the desired keyboards under `System preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources`? If yes you can change the layout of input source pressing: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: I think you missed the point.  When you have a JIS hardware keyboard, the US input source puts things on different keys then when you have a US or European hardware keyboard.  That is what he wants to fix.

Comment: Yes, what @TomGewecke said is what I am trying to fix.